# How to exit loop and continue script with return key without getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python

I'm new to python and need some assistance with an assignment.

My script is this:

```
print "Enter age of individuals (male only!) in order of entered names..."

    age = " "
    ages = []
    while age <> "":
        age = raw_input("Enter a age or press enter: ")
        if int(age) <= 65 and int(age) >= 18:
            print "entry accepted"      
        else:
            print "entry denied: out of age range. Ages 18-65 only!"
        if int(age) < 65 and int(age) > 18:
            ages.append(age)

    ages.remove('')
```

If I press enter to exit the loop and continue to next part of script I get:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Test `age` for empty string *before* trying to convert it into an int. If it's an empty string, either break the loop or skip the age tests.

Comment: Where did you see `<>`?

Comment: Don't use  <> for not-equal-to. According to the docs, " is an obsolete usage kept for backwards compatibility only. New code should always use !=."

Comment: True. And in python3 it does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your method can throw a `ValueError` and you have no `except` for it so you want to rescue the `ValueError`

```
print "Enter age of individuals (male only!) in order of entered names..."
age = " "
ages = []
while age != "":
    age = raw_input("Enter a age or press enter: ")
    try:
        if int(age) <= 65 and int(age) >= 18:
            print "entry accepted"      
        else:
            print "entry denied: out of age range. Ages 18-65 only!"
    except ValueError:
        print "You must enter an integer"
        continue

    if int(age) < 65 and int(age) > 18:
        ages.append(age)

ages.remove('')
```

Comment: That will print `You must enter an integer` before breaking out of the loop.

Comment: It will only print `You must enter an integer` if there is a `ValueError`.

Comment: @EliSadoff> exactly. `int("")` raises a `ValueError`. Thus, it will print `You must enter an integer` before breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
age = raw_input("Enter a age or press enter: ")
```

Outside the while loop above it

And then reads the same line at the end of while loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that right after the input you test for age. If the user inputted nothing (pressing enter), it complains that what the user inputted isn't a number. So, before you check the age you need to add a part which detects if enter was pressed.

```
print "Enter age of individuals (male only!) in order of entered names..."

age = " "
ages = []
while True:
    age = raw_input("Enter a age or press enter: ")
    if age == '':
        break
    if int(age) <= 65 and int(age) >= 18:
        print "entry accepted"      
    else:
        print "entry denied: out of age range. Ages 18-65 only!"
    if int(age) < 65 and int(age) > 18:
        ages.append(age)

ages.remove('')
```